# Passing argument 2 of strcmp makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c

```
void viewonechar(){

char name[25], c[25];
int n;

fp = fopen("Phonebook.txt","r");

printf ("\n\n Enter Character : ");
scanf ("%s",c);

fscanf (fp, "%s %d", name, &n);

while (!feof(fp)){

    if ((strcmp(c, name[0])) == 0){  \\ Warning in here

        printf (" %s +880%d\n",name, n);

    }

    fscanf (fp, "%s %d", name, &n);

}

printf ("\n\n");

fclose(fp);

menu();

}
```

When i compile the code, on the marked line this warning appears, "Passing argument 2 of strcmp makes pointer from integer without a cast". What exactly am i doing wrong?

Comment: If `name` is a `char[25]` array, what do you suppose `name[0]` is ? `strcpy` requires a `const char*` for the second parameter; `name[0]` is *not* that.

Comment: Note that the error message says "integer" not `int`. The `char` type (that is each array element) is an integer type.

Comment: What do you want to compare? Only first character of name and c? What about `if (name[0] == c[0]) {...`? Or all characters from c to the beginning of name `if (strncmp(c, name, strlen(c)) == 0) {...`

Comment: Aside: `while (!feof(fp)){` ==> `while (fscanf (fp, "%s %d", name, &n) == 2){` and remove the two other `fscanf` statements. The loop is best controlled by testing for correct conversion.

Comment: it is also a good habit to compile with full flags like -Wall -Wextra -Werror, as you will see exactly whats wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );

Since `name` is an array of `char`, `name[0]` is a `char`. `strcmp` takes `char` pointers as an arguments, so the `char` you have supplied is implicitly cast to an int-type and then - to the pointer, which produces an undefined behavior and most likely will lead to the segfault.

Comment: I want to get the first character from 'name' and compare it with c. How should i do it?

Comment: @AnikShahriar: since `c` is an array too, presumably you need `if (c[0] == name[0])` to compare the two first characters.

Comment: `c` is an array as well. How you could compare set of characters with one character?

Comment: With `strchr` function.

Comment: @AnikShahriar : If that is what you want to do, then you should ask that question.  `char`s are integer types and can be compared directly with the `==` operator: `if( c[0] == name[0] )`.  Possibly `c` need not be an array but just a single `char`, (i.e. `char c ;`) in which case the `scanf` should change to `scanf ("%c",&c);`

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems.

- Avoid scanf(). See: [Why does everyone say not to use scanf? What should I use instead?](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). Use fgets() instead. Since you are reading just one char, `char c[2]` is sufficient (and also will not read in the `\n` character).
- Always do the error checking for all the standard functions.
- Your loop condition is wrong. See: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)
  You don't need to scan once *outside* the loop if you fix the loop.
- Since you only need to compare the first chars, you can simply use `c[0] == name[0]`.

The below code fixes the above issues:

```
void viewonechar(void) 
{
    char name[25], c[25];
    int n;

    FILE    fp = fopen("Phonebook.txt","r");

    if (!fp) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf ("\n\n Enter Character : ");
    if (fgets(c, sizeof c, stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Input error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (fscanf (fp, "%24s %d", name, &n) == 2) {
        if (c[0] == name[0]) {
            printf (" %s +880%d\n",name, n);
        }  
    }
    printf ("\n\n");
    fclose(fp);
    menu();
}
```